# How can I save whole stack of navigation in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

I am creating a workout app. In home page there are programs in when I tap on a program, a subcategory screen screen opens and when I tap on a subcategory its days screen when I tap on a day its detail screen opens so the stack is home -> subcategory -> days -> day detail. When the user closes the app from a day detail and reopens the app I want to show a continue button from which the user can resume his day and when the user taps the back button he should go back to previous index of stack i.e days screen rather then home screen. How can I do that?

Here is my navigator code:

```js
const MainNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        animationEnabled: true,
        orientation: 'portrait',
      }}>
      <Screen
        name="BottomTabs"
        component={BottomTabs}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.FadeFromBottomAndroid}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="AdditionalWorkout"
        component={AdditionalWorkouts}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="ProgramDetails"
        component={ProgramDetails}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="AssessmentScreen"
        component={AssessmentScreen}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="WorkoutCategory"
        component={WorkoutCategory}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="CalenderImageFullScreen"
        component={CalenderImageFullScreen}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="VideoPlayerScreen"
        component={VideoPlayerScreen}
        options=    {{...TransitionPresets.ModalFadeTransition}}
      />
      <Screen
        name="PaymentScreen"
        component={PaymentScreen}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="PDFScreen"
        component={PDFScreen}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="EditProfile"
        component={EditProfile}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="ChangePassword"
        component={ChangePassword}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="SettingScreen"
        component={SettingScreen}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="WebViewScreen"
        component={WebViewScreen}
        options={
          Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? {...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS}
            : {...TransitionPresets.DefaultTransition}
        }
      />
      <Screen
        name="SubscriptionScreen"
        component={SubscriptionScreen}
        options={{...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS}}
      />
      <Screen
        name="MarkComplete"
        component={MarkComplete}
        options={{...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS}}
      />
      <Screen
        name="DeleteUserScreen"
        component={DeleteUserScreen}
        options={{...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS}}
      />
      <Screen
        name="SwapScreen"
        component={SwapScreen}
        options={{...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS}}
      />
    </Navigator>
  );
};
```

The home screen is in BottomTabs then AdditionalWorkout then ProgramDetails and then AssessmentScreen These are the four screens which are used in above scenario.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/state-persistence/#usage ?

Comment: Hi, you can save on AsyncStorage where the user has stopped and when he clicks on the button continue you can call get the value saved and navigate the user to the same point where he left.

Comment: Yes I can use AsyncStorage but when the user goes to that screen on back press he should navigate to the screen before that not to home screen.